# Parse deleteEventually() method doesn't work (Android code)

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

I'have downloaded the code of the Parse project "OfflineTodos" (see https://github.com/ParsePlatform/OfflineTodos) for Android. It's a very simple sample app, but I'm having problems with it.
I've tried so many combinations to make this work, but I couldn't!
This is part of the original code from class "NewTodoActivity":

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // The todo will be deleted eventually but will
        // immediately be excluded from query results.

        todo.deleteEventually();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

});
```

VERY simple, but it doesn't work! It just delete the local Todo Object, not the server one. I've wait a lot of time with the app running, but nothing happens.
The deleteInBackground() works fine, but I need to use the deleteEventually(), because my app will run in locals with bad internet signals.
I didn't make any changes at the original code.
I want this method (deleteEventually()) to delete immediatelly when the cellphone get network, is it possible? If not, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of android (above version 5) somehow don't seem to accept deleteEventually(). For now, I would suggest a just using deleteInBackground() for the newer versions

```
if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 21) {
    object.deleteInBackground();
}else{
     object.deleteEventually();
}
```